# 8 bit int vs 32 bit int on a 32 bit architechture (GCC)

Tags: c, gcc, memory, types, compiler-optimization

While coding, I try not to use more variable memory than needed and that leads me to write code like this:

```
for (uint8 i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
   ...
}
```

instead of:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
   ...
}
```

(`uint8` instead of `int` because `i` only need to go up to 32)

This would make sense when coding on an 8bit microprocessor. However, am I saving any resources if running this code on a 32bit microprocessor (where `int` might be 16 or 32 bit)? Does a compiler like GCC do any magic/juju underneath when I explicitly use an 8bit `int` on a 32bit architecture?

Comment: Salut ! Have you tried looking at the assembly generated on different architecture? Maybe this could provide some insight on this?

Comment: If you're asking this from a micro-optimization standpoint, you can play with stuff like `intfast8_t`.

Comment: it's `zoozoo`, not `juju`... :-)

Comment: You should look at the assembly if you want to know for sure, but it is pretty likely that you're not saving any resources (unless you have an array) or getting any performance gain.

Comment: As a rule of thumb, don't optimize prematurely, if you want to optimize do it with a reason.

Comment: On local non static variables all belong to stack, for me is not so important. But If you are talking about global structures pre-allocated or "mallocated" its importance is related to the amount of RAM that you need/have.

Comment: thanks! I spent a lot of time working an 8bit processor where "optimizations" like this helped a bit but with more powerful processor that sure is another story!

Comment: My experience is this: Don't even bother to think of a smaller integer type unless you are litterally storing billions of them simultaneously *and you can prove that it's absolutely impossible that you'll ever need more bits*. The last part is important because many, many programmers have needlessly crippled their programs to fail miserably at certain problem sizes just because they tried so safe a few bits!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In most cases, there won't be any memory usage difference because `i` will never be in memory. `i` will be stored in a CPU register, and you can't really use one register to store two variables. So `i` will take one register, `uint8` or `uint32` doesn't matter.

In some rare cases, `i` will actually be stored in memory, because the loop is so big that all the CPU registers are taken. In this case, there is still a good chance you won't gain any memory either, because others multi-bytes variables will be aligned, and `i` will be followed by some useless padding bytes to align the next variable.

Now, if `i` is actually stored in memory, and there are other 8-bit variables to fill the padding, you may save some memory, but it's so little and so unlikely that it probably isn't worth it. Performance-wise, the difference between 8-bit and 32-bit is very architecture dependent, but usually it will be the same.

Also, if you are working in a 64-bit environment, this memory saving is probably non-existent, because the 64-bit call convention impose a huge 16-bytes alignment on the stack (where `i` will be stored if it is in memory).

Comment: I took a look at the assembly code generated and both are identical (the counter variable was in a CPU register as you mentioned) Thanks